# PHP Fetch array in table with individual styling

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that i pull from a database that looks like this

id - name - shortlink - downloadurl - count - date

Now I want to display that array as a table so the administartor of the site can se the content of the database. For that, I'm using this code:

```
function build_table($array){
                    // start table
                    $html = '<table id="usertable">';
                    // header row
                    $html .= '<tr class="header">';
                    foreach($array[0] as $key=>$value){
                            $html .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
                        }
                    $html .= '</tr>';

                    // data rows
                    foreach( $array as $key=>$value){
                        $html .= '<tr>';
                        foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
                            $html .= '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';
                        }
                        $html .= '</tr>';
                    }

                    // finish table and return it

                    $html .= '</table>';
                    return $html;
```

And it works great.
The problem is that i wan't do display some of the columns with a different code. E.g. 'downloadurl' which is an webadress, i want to make clickable. I just can't figure out how to split up the function so that i can write the code for the individual columns.

Comment: Check the `$key` and use conditionals (assuming `$array` is associative, indexed will be a bit more cryptic to future developers).

Comment: You can use a ```switch``` conditional to have a $key printed like you want.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Can you show me how to do it? I pretty new to php so i'm not shure of what you guys mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something similar to the following:

#### using conditionals

This is probably the most straight forward way to go about handling different attributes per column - not without its drawbacks (noted below)

```
// data rows
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
  $html .= '<tr>';
  foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
    if ($key2 == 'downloadurl') {
      $html .= '<td><a href="' . $value2 . '">Download</a></td>';
    } else {
      $html .= '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';
    }
  }
  $html .= '</tr>';
}
```

#### using switch statement

If you decide on this route, it may be a bit easier to manage in the long run as `if () elseif () else()` can become difficult to read over time.

```
foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
  switch($key2) {
    case 'downloadurl':
      $html .= '<td><a href="' . $value2 . '">Download</a></td>';
    break;

    default:
      $html .= '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Could only make the switch statement work for the first link. The rest just displayed the adress. But using the conditionals worked.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to generate urls:

```
function getURL($downloadURL)
{
    $html = "<a href = '$downloadURL'>Download</a>";
    return $html;
}
```

And your `function build_table()`:

```
function build_table($array){
    // start table
    $html = '<table id = "usertable">';
    // header row
    $html .= '<tr class = "header">';
    foreach($array[0] as $key => $value){
         $html .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';
    // data rows
    foreach( $array as $key => $value){
         $html .= '<tr>';
         foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
              $value2 = ($key2 == 'downloadurl') ? getURL($value2) : $value2;
              $html .= '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';
         }
         $html .= '</tr>';
      }
      // finish table and return it
      $html .= '</table>';
      return $html;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this approach. I appreciate that you're attempting to separate concerns but, this is really just unnecessarily convoluting code. `getURL()` doesn't actually *get* anything outside of what's provided. Furthermore, you're still calculating when to invoke within the loop cycle - And this approach leaves OP with less room to perform different views per column. Overall, if the point was separating out view, I would have suggested a view templating framework rather than forcing it into an adjunct answer.